# Which version of Safari has the user agent string "Safari/537.36"?

Tags: safari

Our site analytics tool (we use Google Analytics) has shown a huge influx of Safari users (about 40% of all users, which is more than Chrome's 36%!), with over 17,000 of them reported as being on Safari version 537.36. The [most recent version](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safari_version_history) as of this writing is Safari 10.0.2 (and we only get about 2,500 users on 10.0.x).

We're really surprised by this development. Which version of Safari has the user agent string "Safari/537.36"?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems to be a slightly dated version of Google Chrome (45.0.2454.85). The use agent strings seem to get pretty ridiculous nowadays, so I normally use the Browser Info tool to parse exactly whats going on.

[Browser Info](http://www.browser-info.net/useragent?q=Mozilla%2F5.0%20(Windows%20NT%206.1%3B%20WOW64)%20AppleWebKit%2F537.36%20(KHTML%2C%20like%20Gecko)%20Chrome%2F45.0.2454.85%20Safari%2F537.36)

Comment: The influx we see is is in the same ballpark as our Chrome usage, so this does seem likely. Funny, we use Google Analytics for our site reporting, yet it's a Google browser that's causing the issue. Guess the right hand doesn't know what the left hand is doing.

Answer (score 3):

Then can also be Chrome users. This is what my Chrome version shows:

> V8
>   7.0.276.22
>   User Agent
>   Mozilla/5.0 (X11; CrOS x86_64 11021.34.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.41 Safari/537.36

Answer (score 0):

Safari/537.36 is the webkit version, that is present on Safari under iOS, Blackberry, PS since PS3, Amazon Kinder ...

But be careful, some UAs was detect under Linux os, with chrome and webkit version meaning that users use an iOS virtual box (or other) under Linux OS.
Most of time the webkit version is also an old version (more than 10 years, like 537.xx in 2012).
In conclusion : bot for sniffing websites because, for me, no bad request.
The black hole respond with 200 header without any really interresting activity after that.